# Firebase web application - authentication and cloud messaging

Tags: android, firebase, web-applications, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-authentication

I am following the guide at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging which explains how to set up a web app for Firebase Cloud Messaging.

What I'm wondering is how I would incorporate authentication into this process. What I aim to do is to have a user sign in with their Google account to both an Android device and this web application. Afterwards, the Android device would send upstream messages which would be processed by my app server and sent to the web application.

How would the application server connect the user's Google account to each instance id token - created on the webapp and the Android app?

What I'm thinking is that while I send the instance id to the application server, I also send the authenticated user id with it. The app server would be able to match the two instance id tokens together and pass a message along.

Is this process correct?

Comment: It is very common to associate the user's Instance ID tokens with their UID. But whether this is correct for your app depends on what concern you're trying to address with it.